# Is right to use mail no-reply like this format in PHP

Tags: php

I have PHP mail function like this for no-reply:

```
$eol = PHP_EOL;
$headers = 'Reply-To: COMPANY NAME  noreply@example.com'.$eol;
```

I want the company name to be shown but recipients will not see or reply to my company's email address

Comment: You should probably set the `from:` adress to the noreply adress as well if you want to hide your real adress.

Comment: In what way  can I do that?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what i was looking for. I later solved the problem. Incase if there is anyone out here looking for the same solution to this problem. the code below solves it

```
 $eol = PHP_EOL;
 $headers = "FROM: MY COMPANY <noreply@example.com>".$eol;
```